# How to save the names of clicked objects to a text file (Visual Basic)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text-files

I am doing a cinema booking system as my A-Level Computing project, I am using labels as seats, when they are clicked they turn green and I am trying to save the name of each clicked label to an array that will be later saved to a file. This is the procedure for when a seat is clicked:

```
    Private Sub lblA1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblA1.Click, lblA2.Click, lblA3.Click, lblA4.Click, lblA5.Click, lblA6.Click, lblA7.Click, lblB1.Click, lblB2.Click, lblB3.Click, lblB4.Click, lblB5.Click, lblB6.Click, lblB7.Click, lblC1.Click, lblC2.Click, lblC3.Click, lblC4.Click, lblC5.Click, lblC6.Click, lblC7.Click, lblD1.Click, lblD2.Click, lblD3.Click, lblD4.Click, lblD5.Click, lblD6.Click, lblD7.Click, lblE1.Click, lblE2.Click, lblE3.Click, lblE4.Click, lblE5.Click, lblE6.Click, lblE7.Click, lblF1.Click, lblF2.Click, lblF3.Click, lblF4.Click, lblF5.Click, lblF6.Click, lblF7.Click, lblG1.Click, lblG2.Click, lblG3.Click, lblG4.Click, lblG5.Click, lblG6.Click, lblG7.Click, lblH1.Click, lblH2.Click, lblH3.Click, lblH4.Click, lblH5.Click, lblH6.Click, lblH7.Click, lblI1.Click, lblI2.Click, lblI3.Click, lblI4.Click, lblI5.Click, lblI6.Click, lblI7.Click, lblJ1.Click, lblJ2.Click, lblJ3.Click, lblJ4.Click, lblJ5.Click, lblJ6.Click, lblJ7.Click, lblK1.Click, lblK2.Click, lblK3.Click, lblK4.Click, lblK5.Click, lblK6.Click, lblK7.Click, lblL1.Click, lblL2.Click, lblL3.Click, lblL4.Click, lblL5.Click, lblL6.Click, lblL7.Click
    ClickedBox = CType(sender, Label)
    If ClickedBox.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue Then 'Checks if seat is free
        ClickedBox.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen 'Changes colour of seats clicked to green
        ClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
        TotalNoOfSeats = TotalNoOfSeats + 1
        strSeats(intCounter3) = ClickedBox.Name
        intCounter3 = intCounter3 + 1
    Else
        MsgBox("This seat has already been booked")
    End If
End Sub
```

When the user clicks the 'Book Seats' button I have called a procedure that attempts to save the array of seat names to a text file. The following code is the procedure:

```
    Sub SaveSeats()
    Dim intloop As Integer
    FileWriter = New StreamWriter("Seats " + AddFilm.strFilms(1, intSelectedFilm) + ".txt")
    FileWriter.WriteLine(intCounter3)
    For intloop = 0 To intCounter3
        FileWriter.WriteLine(strSeats(intloop))
    Next
    FileWriter.Close()
End Sub
```

On the line that contains:

```
    FileWriter.WriteLine(strSeats(intloop))
```

I get the following error: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array."
Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit**: i have used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253883/284240) but now i have another problem:

The error containing: "ObjectDisposedException - Cannot write to a closed TextWriter." appears on the line:

```
 FileWriter.WriteLine(SeatList(intloop))
```

This is the procedure I am using now to Save the list to the text file:

```
Sub SaveSeats()
    Dim intloop As Integer
    FileWriter = New StreamWriter("Seats " + AddFilm.strFilms(1, intSelectedFilm) + ".txt")
    FileWriter.WriteLine(NoOfClickedSeats)
    For intloop = 1 To NoOfClickedSeats
        FileWriter.WriteLine(SeatList(intloop))
        FileWriter.Close()
    Next  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indices are zero based, so you have to subtract 1 from `intCounter3`:

```
For intloop As Int32 = 0 To intCounter3 - 1
    FileWriter.WriteLine(strSeats(intloop))
Next
```

Consider that `intCounter3` is 1 (the array contains one element). You would try to access the second element with `intCounter3(1)` which causes  the  `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

By the way, you should choose more meaningful names than `intCounter3`, otherwise it'll be soon difficult to understand your code for you or others.

**Edit**: another problem with code is that you are resizing the array without redim. You should use a `List(Of String)` instead which can be resized:

So instead of:

```
strSeats(intCounter3) = ClickedBox.Name
```

Use a list instead and it's `Add` method:

```
Private SeatList As New ist(Of String)

Private Sub lblA1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblA1.Click, lblA2.Click, lblA3.Click, lblA4.Click, lblA5.Click, lblA6.Click, lblA7.Click, lblB1.Click, lblB2.Click, lblB3.Click, lblB4.Click, lblB5.Click, lblB6.Click, lblB7.Click, lblC1.Click, lblC2.Click, lblC3.Click, lblC4.Click, lblC5.Click, lblC6.Click, lblC7.Click, lblD1.Click, lblD2.Click, lblD3.Click, lblD4.Click, lblD5.Click, lblD6.Click, lblD7.Click, lblE1.Click, lblE2.Click, lblE3.Click, lblE4.Click, lblE5.Click, lblE6.Click, lblE7.Click, lblF1.Click, lblF2.Click, lblF3.Click, lblF4.Click, lblF5.Click, lblF6.Click, lblF7.Click, lblG1.Click, lblG2.Click, lblG3.Click, lblG4.Click, lblG5.Click, lblG6.Click, lblG7.Click, lblH1.Click, lblH2.Click, lblH3.Click, lblH4.Click, lblH5.Click, lblH6.Click, lblH7.Click, lblI1.Click, lblI2.Click, lblI3.Click, lblI4.Click, lblI5.Click, lblI6.Click, lblI7.Click, lblJ1.Click, lblJ2.Click, lblJ3.Click, lblJ4.Click, lblJ5.Click, lblJ6.Click, lblJ7.Click, lblK1.Click, lblK2.Click, lblK3.Click, lblK4.Click, lblK5.Click, lblK6.Click, lblK7.Click, lblL1.Click, lblL2.Click, lblL3.Click, lblL4.Click, lblL5.Click, lblL6.Click, lblL7.Click
    ClickedBox = CType(sender, Label)
    If ClickedBox.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue Then 'Checks if seat is free
        ClickedBox.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen 'Changes colour of seats clicked to green
        ClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
        TotalNoOfSeats = TotalNoOfSeats + 1
        SeatList.Add(ClickedBox.Name)
        intCounter3 = intCounter3 + 1
    Else
        MsgBox("This seat has already been booked")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**: according to your last edit related to the `ObjectDisposedException`:

You cannot close the writer in the loop since a closed writer cannot be used anymore. So you should close it after the loop.

```
For intloop = 0 To NoOfClickedSeats - 1
    FileWriter.WriteLine(SeatList(intloop))
Next  
FileWriter.Close()
```

or use the `Using`-statement which also ensures that it gets closed/disposed in case of an error:

```
Using FileWriter = New StreamWriter("Seats " + AddFilm.strFilms(1, intSelectedFilm) + ".txt")
    For intloop = 0 To NoOfClickedSeats - 1
        FileWriter.WriteLine(SeatList(intloop))
    Next 
End Using
```

Comment: Do I need to start intcounter3 at the value of 0?

Comment: @user3061609: if you need to resize an array constantly use a `List(Of String)` instead. Edited my answer.

Comment: OK I have never used a list before, how would I save the contents of the list to the text file?

Comment: You can use `File.WriteAllLines(path,String.Join(Environment.NewLine,SeatList))` or simply use it in a loop the same way you would use an array. Lists also use arrays as backing field, so they also have an indexer.

Comment: @JoshCooper yes... you need to start intcounter3 at a value of 0. Also as recomended earlier rename the counter something more meaningful such as selectedSeatsCount

Comment: ok it saves to a file now but instead of saving the name of the label it saves this: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: @TimSchmelter The list that you told me to use doesn't save to the text file properly, anymore help is appreciated

Comment: @JoshCooper: you can either use the code i've shown in my last comment which uses `String.Join` or use a loop(`foreach` or `for`) and a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt(v=vs.110).aspx). However, you should not write the `List` but the strings in it (therefore the loop or `string.Join`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I attempted to use a for loop before and instead of saving the names of the label it saved this on every line: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: @JoshCooper: Then you have not used `FileWriter.WriteLine(SeatList(intloop))`(as in your code above) but `FileWriter.WriteLine(SeatList)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have tried it that way too and I get an error containing: "System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled - Cannot write to a closed TextWriter." But this error only shows after it has saved the name of 1 of the clicked labels.

Comment: @JoshCooper: you need to edit your question and show some code. It's impossible to help in  comments. You should use the `Using`-statement instead of `FileWriter.Close()` and have the loop inside of the using not outside.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have Edited the question for you

Comment: @JoshCooper: don't replace the original question with another, then you should ask a different question instead. Now my answer is off-topic and not helpful for anybody. I have edited your question to rollback to revision 1 and added your next problem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OK sorry, when using the "using statement" I get the same error as beforehand where the "intloop" is out of range

Comment: @JoshCooper: have a look at the first sentence of my answer ;) (i have edited my answer to provide the correct loop)